# Incompleteness theorems in encoding schemes other than Gödel numbering

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms, proof-theory

Gödel's proof of his incompleteness theorems makes use of Gödel numbering, which is a device that allows a theory of arithmetic $S$ (e.g. PRA) to express and reason about metamathematical statements about a theory $T$ ($T$ must satisfy some conditions that I am omitting for the sake of brevity).

Gödel numbering seems however unnecessary in the case one decides to carry metamathematics in an adequately powerful set theory, say ZFC just to fix one, as opposed to a theory of arithmetic. As done in proof theory, one defines formal languages, axioms, theorems, deductions, rules of inference, theories, etc. as mathematical objects (which are ultimately sets). Having taken care of this, we can view ZFC as a mathematical object in the universe of ZFC, or to be more precise there is an object in the universe of ZFC which is a carbon-copy of ZFC. To avoid confusion, I will refer to this carbon-copy object as $\overline{\text{ZFC}}$ and statements in the language of $\overline{\text{ZFC}}$ will be overlined. Now the sentence 
 "$\overline{(\emptyset = \emptyset) \wedge \neg (\emptyset = \emptyset})$ is not a theorem of $\overline{\text{ZFC}}$" is a sentence in ZFC which asserts the consistency of $\overline{\text{ZFC}}$.

Do the incompleteness theorems prevent this sentence from being provable (assuming ZFC is consistent), even though Gödel numbering was not used to implement it?

Comment: Yes, on reasonable assumptions. Whatever the details of your representation might be, by which ZFC can talk about its axioms, proofs, theorems, etc., the definitions of the required predicates can be *effective*, the representations can be hereditarily finite objects, and thus via a different kind of coding it can all be mapped *back* to arithmetic and recursive functions. Thus Godel's metamathematical proof goes through just as for PA, with only notational changes.

Comment: I'm not certain this question is well formed. The incompleteness theorems make a claim that a sufficiently strong theory can't be consistent and complete. Supposing ZFC is consistent and sufficiently strong, it follows that it can't be complete. I think we're on the same page there, but where you lose me is with $\overline{ZFC}$. Assuming $\overline{ZFC}$ is (be it thought of as a set) properly contained in ZFC, then it trivially wouldn't be complete since ZFC is a proper extension and is by assumption consistent. So $\overline{ZFC}$=ZFC? But then by incompleteness it's not complete.

Comment: @aaron Yes this notion of $\overline{ZFC}$ could be pinned down more firmly. Giving the benefit of the doubt, I assume(d) it's just the set of all representations of theorems, so that $\overline{\sigma} \in \overline{ZFC}$ (for $\sigma$ an actual sentence) is analogous to Godel's provability predicate $Beweis(\mathbf{n})$ where $\mathbf{n}$ is a numeral denoting the Godel number $n$ of a sentence.

Comment: @aaron ZFC and $\overline{\text{ZFC}}$ are conceptually different things (hence the different notation): the first refers to the background theory in which we are working and the second to a mathematical object within the universe of that theory. As BrianO said, in kind of implementation I have in mind, that object is the set of representations of theorems in ZFC.

Comment: I see, as in numerals vs. numbers. I would suspect that supposing zfc were consistent, we would number it, then the bijection of that numbering onto $\overline{ZFC}$ would be subject to the incompleteness theorems if pinning down PA were itself decidable. Ineterstingly, the Tarski axioms are complete despite containing the natural numbers since pinning down PA from the axioms is not decidable. So my suspicion is most certainly suspicious and perhaps not true.

Comment: A new [paper on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05728) discussing how to express Gödel 2nd incompleteness theorem.

Comment: @BrianO Do you mean to say that there is an encoding of ZFC into arithmetic such that composing this encoding with the representation I gave is exactly Gödel numbering? And furthermore, the sentence "$\overline{(\emptyset = \emptyset) \wedge \neg (\emptyset = \emptyset})$ is not a theorem of $\overline{\text{ZFC}}$" would be mapped to a sentence that is provably equivalent to one that Gödel incompleteness theorems say is unprovable?

Comment: Hmm I wouldn't say you "gave" a representation, just alluded to one. I assumed that formula representatives are hereditarily finite sets, i.e. things in $V_{\omega}$. Everything in $V_{\omega}$ is a finite tree ("children" = members), and can be coded by integers in various effective ways. On the integer side, there is no one Godel numbering — we pick one and stick to it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand your question. However, there is an effective way to code formulas as hereditarily finite sets (and if you are interested in an explicit construction, I could mail you a scan of my handwritten notes) which can be effectively converted to a Gödel numbering via the Ackermann coding function. This also demonstrates that Gödel's incompleteness applies to this form of coding.